# Safari change select height

Tags: css, safari

I can't change `select` `height`, with all browser working fine, but Safari no, where can be problem? Also I try make class `.style select`, but not working.

```
select {
width: 170px; 
height: 25px;
}
```

Comment: I think the height of a select in Safari is linked to the text size and you can't set it on its own.

Comment: You might be able to change it with `line-height`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
-webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
```

Comment: Doesn't works with Safari on Windows machine, but Line-Height property is enough to style the height of Select tag

Comment: This is the only working method since Safari Version 10.1.2. Line height no longer works.

Comment: This does not work for me, 1/1/2020. I have to set `-webkit-appearance: none;` and use a css hack to add my own drop-down arrow icon

Answer (score 31):

To style a select in Safari, you first have to turn off the os styling:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Comment: True, but this will hide the dropdown arrow. Therefore the best option is line-height (see answer above).

Comment: This does hide the drop-down arrow, but it does also successfully strip the offensive styling - clean palette. +1

Comment: This can be useful for those making a stylized select drop down by hiding the original select and having an overlay to look like the styled drop down.

Answer (score 27):

You can also use

```
line-height: 25px
```

which doesn't affect other browsers, but fixes this bug in Safari

Comment: `line-height` seems to be ignored 9.1.3, however `height: 25px` is working. 

Unfortunately `min-height` is also not working.

Comment: `height` or `line-height` does not work in version 10.1.2

Answer (score 3):

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    select {
        -webkit-appearance: menulist-button !important;
        line-height:24px !important;
    }
}
```

This code ensures the same height across browsers.

Answer (score 3):

The best way use modernizer detector and give safari class select menu a

```
line-height: 20px;
```

or you can use jquery UI select menu to solve this by another cross-browser wy.

Answer (score 2):

at least on iPad the select is not rendered for padding or line-height but instead will render given height and center vertically the  value

```
select {
   -webkit-appearance:menu-item; // or menulist-button
   -moz-appearance:menu-item;
   height:2.4em;   // this must be calculated to match other input types     
}

input[type="text"], select {
    min-width:12em;  
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

the only thing unresolved now is background which is predefined and imutable

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me until I used inline style:

```
<select name="pickupsel" id="pickups" style="line-height:33px">
```

Somehow Safari (latest Windows version, 5.1.7) doesn't read this style property from CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { select { -webkit-appearance: menulist-button !important; line-height:24px !important; } }
```

Give `line-height` according your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I am solving this in 2022:

```
select, input {
    font-size: 14px; //or whatever
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 3em;
    padding: 0; //top and bottom must be 0
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: This works for the height but removes the up/down arrows for me on Safari 15.6.1, macOS 12.5.1

Comment: @RCWhim - Yes, if you want to style it yourself, you will have to do the arrows also. Hence the `appearance:none`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am solving this in 2022:

```css
    select {
      background-color: inherit;
    }
```