# How to set height Or Padding in select box (dropdown box) for safari and chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I want to set height or width in  **selectbox**  .

```
<?php $subjectList=array('0'=>'Questions','1'=>'Feedback / Suggestions','2'=>'Location Owner Inquiry' ,'3'=>'Other');?>

<select name="vSubject" data-errormessage-value-missing="Select Reason!" id="vSubject"  >
   <option value="" >-Select One-</option>
   <?php foreach($subjectList as $r=>$k) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $r?>" ><?php echo $k?></option>
   <?php }?>
</select>
```

Padding and height is not working in SAFARI. 
So suggest some  solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252835/safari-change-select-height

Comment: And what about 'option' ? If I want to set height or padding, thn ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try this CSS for your drop down?

```
overflow: hidden;
border: none;
outline: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

For Safari you can try

```
-webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
```

so that width and height will work ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252835/safari-change-select-height))

then you can use background,font-family,padding etc to further enchant your custom select tag. It worked for me in Safari/Chrome/FF ...

EDIT:

Editing option tag is not that easy. You can use the css below but everything is not customisable unfortunately

```
select option {
    margin:40px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    color:#fff;
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

sources: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12836227/change-select-box-option-background-color),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8430279/how-to-style-the-option-with-only-css)

Comment: And what about 'option' ?

If I want to set height or padding, thn ?

Comment: option is the one thing you can't edit properly unfortunately. I think background property works (colour and stuff) but height and padding I'm afraid not. see my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8PMtX/5/)** Use a combination of text-indent and line-height to create the illusion of padding. Works in Safari.Should work in IE as well.

```
#vSubject {
    text-indent:15px; line-height:28px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
select {
 width: 170px; 
 height: 25px;
 -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;
}
```

Comment: And what about 'option' ? If I want to set height or padding, thn ?

Answer (score -1):

```
select { line-height : 28px; float : left; }
```